# What new functionality is available through delegates and events in C# 3?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

I feel that I am not utilizing all the features  of delegates/events available in .NET 3.5 and beyond. And more or less still  using delegates power available in 2.0.  I would appreciate if you tell me how delegates/events should be used now, tricks, short-cuts.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

***Jon suggested his publication on this subject, and I am posting here for easier navigations:***

A few of my articles which may be relevant:

- [Events](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/events.html)
- [Delegates in C# 2.0](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/csharp2/delegates.html)
- [Closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx)
- [C# 2 bluffers' guide](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BluffersGuide2.aspx)
- [C# 3 bluffers' guide](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BluffersGuide3.aspx)

My book, C# in Depth, has a whole chapter devoted to delegates (chapter 5). Unfortunately that's not one of the free ones :(

ps.  I couldn't find a duplicate of this question but did look through many on this theme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few of my articles which may be relevant:

- [Events](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/events.html)
- [Delegates in C# 2.0](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/csharp2/delegates.html)
- [Closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx)
- [C# 2 bluffers' guide](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BluffersGuide2.aspx)
- [C# 3 bluffers' guide](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BluffersGuide3.aspx)

My book, [C# in Depth](http://manning.com/skeet), has a whole chapter devoted to delegates (chapter 5). Unfortunately that's not one of the free ones :(

The main changes in summary (as Jared said, these are language changes - .NET itself hasn't changed much beyond them becoming generic, and the framework supplying the handy `Func` and `Action` delegates):

C# 2:

- Method group conversions:

  ```
  // Old:
  button.Click += new EventHandler(HandleClick);
  // New:
  button.Click += HandleClick;
  ```
- Anonymous methods:

  ```
  button.Click += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Click!"); };
  ```
- Covariance/contravariance:

  ```
  EventHandler generalHandler = LogEvent;
  button.Click += generalHandler;
  button.KeyPress += generalHandler; // Event type is KeyPressEventHandler
  ```

C# 3:

- Lambda expressions:

  ```
  button.Click += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("Click!");
  ```

  or more importantly:

  ```
  var people = list.Where(person => person.Name != "Jon")
                   .OrderBy(person => person.Age);
  ```

Comment: Unfortunate for *us* you mean ;)

Comment: Well, that depends - if a teaser chapter ended up being enough to get someone to buy the book...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, thanks, I have all of them print out and read more than once... looking to dark corners....DARK!!!!

Comment: @Jon - A teaser chapter was enough for me :)

Comment: Care to elaborate your “old/new” distinction for method group conversion? I don't get it (or isn't it rather the other way round?).

Comment: @Konrad: Yes, other way round.

Comment: @Sasha: I think I'm out of ideas for the minute. And I need to put the kids to bed :)

Answer (score 1):

Delegates didn't change at all 2.0 -> 3.5.  What changed was a lot of items around them

1. The System.Core.dll (finally) added reusable delegates in the form of Func<> and Action<>
2. C# and VB gained a bit of a functional flavor with lambda expressions.  This gave the languages very succinct syntax for expression a delegate operation.  C# had anonymous methods in 2.0 but they just don't compare with the succint nature of lambda expressions

   ```
    list.Where(x => x > 42);
   ```
3. LINQ in it's underpinnings exposes a series of APIs that operate purely on delegates.

So really delegetase haven't changed, just the uses.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using delegates for quick and dirty async operations?  You can call the BeginInvoke and EndInvoke methods to perform async operations on the ThreadPool.

```
// Definition.
delegate string TransformDelegate(string input);

// Client code.  This is some lengthy operation.  You can also
// assign a function here if you want.
TransformDelegate t = (x) => ...;

// Begin invoking.
t.BeginInvoke("input", (ar) => 
{
    // Call end invoke.
    string result = t.EndInvoke(ar);

    // Dispose of wait handle, known issue documented here.
    // https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=94068
    using (IDisposable d = ar.WaitHandle) { }

    // Process end result here.  Remember, on another thread now.
}, null);
```